# How do I clear an snap.svg canvus after Snap.Load

Tags: javascript, svg

```
<script>

var s = Snap();

function letter()
  { 
    var nameElement = document.getElementById("someInput");
    var theName = nameElement.value;
    var letter = theName.slice(0, -3)
    Snap.load(theName+".svg", function (f) {
    s.append(f.select("g"));
    });
  }

</script>
```

The above code generates a different svg when i type a different letter into a textbox. When i try use the textbox more than once the the svg's start to overlap. Is there anyway to clear the canvas in the function before a new svg is loaded

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
function letter(){ 
    var nameElement = document.getElementById("someInput");
    var theName = nameElement.value;
    var letter = theName.slice(0, -3);
    Snap.load(theName+".svg", function (f) {
      s.clear();//just add this....
      s.append(f.select("g"));
    });
}
```